# Is there a standard way to cite Buddhist scriptures?

Tags: scripture

Is there anything for Buddhist texts equivalent to the [typical way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_citation) of citing Biblical verses? (e.g. John 1:1)

[Related question on [Tripitaka Section Numbering](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3770/tripitaka-section-numbering).]

Answer (score 1):

As I keep looking myself, this seems to be less well-specified than one might hope. But a couple of useful things so far lead me to one option being something like:

> *DN 16 (PTS DN ii 72)*

Trouble is, although that's probably quite a precise form, it's for the Pali. See below for the references that help explain it.

- [Access to Insight](http://www.accesstoinsight.org), as always, has [***something useful to say***](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/abbrev.html). Unfortunately, the especially relevant-looking link in [note #1](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/abbrev.html#fn-1x) at the bottom of that page is dead. However, I googled for the title and I think I found it, or something like it as follows:
- [***The Contents and Structure of the Pali Canon and its Commentaries***](http://www.budsas.org/ebud/ebsut028.htm#Canon) on [this page](http://www.budsas.org/ebud/ebsut028.htm) at [BuddhaSasana](http://www.budsas.org/index.htm). (I also searched for it on https://ukabs.org.uk, which is the organization that AtoI's reference suggests originally hosted the document, but I couldn't find it).

Comment: I have been having the same problem: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3770/tripitaka-section-numbering. Perhaps if you can find a PDF copy of the latter books this might help solving this.

Comment: Thanks Suminda. I've added a link to your question since it's almost certainly going to be useful to anyone interested in mine.