# Where is DN.iii.106?

Tags: reference-request

I have been trying to find a sutta DN.iii.106 on [suttacentral.net](https://suttacentral.net/) but  couldn't find it. On suttacentral.net DN.iii.99 is given and after that DN.iii.117, DN.iii.106 is missing. I failed to find it on [accesstoinsight.org](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/index.html) as well.

I am looking for it because it talks about the 7 factors of enlightenment which is crucial for the destruction of craving.

Can anyone please give me the link to DN.iii.106 ?

Comment: See also [Tripitaka Section Numbering](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3770/254) (and the answers to [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/28223/254)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [suttacentral](https://suttacentral.net/dn-pathikavagga) ...

- DN 28 starts with DN iii 99
- DN 29 starts with DN iii 117

... so I think that DN.iii.106 is near the middle of [DN 28](https://suttacentral.net/dn28/en/sujato).

Answer (score 2):

[Long Discourses of the Buddha (Digha Nikaya)](http://lirs.ru/lib/sutra/Long_Discourses_of_the_Buddha(Digha_Nikaya).Walshe.pdf)

[image]