# Suttas of 6 qualities of dhamma

Tags: reference-request, sutta-reference

The 6 qualities of the Dhamma are

> 1. Svakkhato, 2. Samditthiko, 3. Akaliko, 4. Ehipassiko, 5. Opaneyiko, 6. Paccattam veditabbo vinnunhi

according to [here](https://www.dhammawiki.com/index.php/6_qualities_of_the_Dhamma).

This website claims that the source is

> Anguttara Nikaya 11.12

But I couldn't find such words in this sutta.

Does anyone knows the source of these words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the numbering of the suttas especially in Anguttara Nikaya could be off by one or two in either direction, due to the original source of the edition e.g. Pali Text Society, Mahasangiti Tipitaka, Buddha Jayanti Tipitaka, Vipassana Research Institute,  etc. Please also see [Tripitaka Section Numbering](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3770/471).

I found the stated text in [AN 11.11](https://suttacentral.net/an11.11/en/sujato) (below) in SuttaCentral, translated by Ven. Sujato, which is based on the Mahasangiti Tipitaka edition.

> ‘The teaching is well explained by the Buddha—visible in this very
> life, immediately effective, inviting inspection, relevant, so that
> sensible people can know it for themselves.’
>
> *‘svākkhāto bhagavatā dhammo sandiṭṭhiko akāliko ehipassiko opaneyyiko paccattaṁ veditabbo viññūhī’ti.*

However, on AccessToInsight.org, it's [AN 11.12](https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an11/an11.012.than.html) (below), translated by Ven. Thanissaro, and it seems to be based on the Pali Text Society edition.

> 'The
> Dhamma is well-expounded by the Blessed One, to be seen here & now,
> timeless, inviting verification, pertinent, to be realized by the wise
> for themselves.'
>
> *'svākkhāto bhagavatā dhammo sandiṭṭhiko akāliko ehipassiko opanayiko paccattaṃ veditabbo viññūhī'ti*

The Pali word *opaneyyiko* above is a bit different from *opanayiko* below, if you notice.

Comment: Thank you so much. In the end, it was AN 11.11., But not AN 11.12. Great.