# Four kinds of people. "attahitaya ca patipanno". Good for yourself and others

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutta-reference

According to [this website](https://maithri.com/links/articles/the-buddhist-concept-of-social-welfare/), it says...

> The Buddha classified persons into four kinds on the basis of one’s attitude towards one’s own interest and one’s attitude towards the interest of others.

I started source text research and I found [this website](https://84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=21&A=2660&w=&modeTY=2&pagebreak=), using the search word of

> attahitaya ca patipanno parahitaya ca

The website says its source text is

> Sutta Pitaka Vol 13 : Sutta. Aṅ. (2): catukkanipāto 96

But I could not find such text on [SuttaCentral](https://suttacentral.net/).

Does anyone know the correct index of the text?

Answer (score 2):

[AN 4.95](https://suttacentral.net/an4.95/en/sujato)

> one who practices to benefit both themselves and others
> *attahitāya ceva paṭipanno parahitāya ca*

There's more than one numbering system, as you can [see here](https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/index.html#an4), for example AN 4.95 and A ii 95

> AN 4.95: Chavalata Sutta — Wood from a Pyre/The Firebrand {A ii 95}

See also [Tripitaka Section Numbering](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3770/254)